# Following, and saving, the flow of code

Tags: c, trace, kvm

I was wondering if there is any way of compiling a program (my own program, or an open source program), with which I can follow the flow of that program when I execute it. Ideally, I would like to output the specific methods which the program goes through when it executes. Each time it calls a specific method, I would like to output that it has done so, which I would like to save to a file for later analysis.

For example, I am trying to better understand the flow within KVM (an open source hypervisor) but there are obviously many lines of code, and would be impossible for me to know where the code goes unless I dedicated possibly weeks to finding out.

The code I am looking at is written mostly in C, but also uses other languages. Any ideas please?

Comment: You're looking for a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

KVM is a subsystem of Linux kernel, so you should use ftrace (http://lwn.net/Articles/322666/) for tracing kernel-space code.